# Post image on facebook get error: domain = com.facebook.sdk, code = 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, facebook

I want to post photo on Facebook. I got user details but photo didn't get posted.

I used Facebook SDK.The error is:

> error: domain = com.facebook.sdk, code = 5.

Other app key is working in my app but my key is not working.

I gave all permissions like public but photo didn't get posted.

I have used below code..

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" parameters:postParams HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
    NSString *alertText;
    if (error)
    {
        [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] hudEndProcessMethod];

        alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"error: domain = %@, code = %d", error.domain, error.code];            
        NSLog(@"alertText==%@",alertText);
        // [alert show];
    } else {
        alertText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Posted action, id: %@", [result objectForKey:@"id"]];
        [(AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] hudEndProcessMethod];
        // NSLog(@"posted succesfully with ID %@",[result objectForKey:@"id"]);
    }
}];
```

Comment: Please, post error `userInfo` for more details.

Comment: user information get but photo not posted..so, its give error: domain = com.facebook.sdk, code = 5.

Comment: No, log here contents of `[error userInfo]`.